# How do I get an NfcAdapter callback for card removed?

Tags: android, nfc

The Android documentation tells about putting the `NfcAdapter` into reader mode, which registers an `NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback`. This is fine for discovering tags, but can I also be notified somehow of the user *removing* the tag from the device? This seems to be possible with USB devices, can it be done too through the builtin nfc reader on phones and tablets?